# What is the "0xXXXX" syntax when learning bit manipulation? (where X is a capital alphanumeric character)

Tags: syntax, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to learn about bit manipulation by doing a few problems after learning the basics and in some solutions, I seem to see this format. For example:

```
N = (N & 0xAAAA)>>1 | (N & 0x5555)<<1
```

What does this do (specifically the 0XAAAA and 0x5555)? And what is the name of this syntax or format so that I can look it up?

Thanks

Comment: Those are hexadecimal values.

Comment: Each character is representative of 1-16 so, 0-9 then A->F.  this is essentally a base 16 notation of a number.   Normally humans work in Base 10, but in computers, base 2 and base 16 are very common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are hexadecimal values. The 0xAAAA is equivalent to 1010101010101010.  A = 1010 (in binary).  So therefore 4 A's is four sequences of the binary value.

When you combine that with a binary &, you look for all the bits of N that coincide with the pattern 1010... where both bits are 1 and keep those bits only.

Example:

```
  1110101010101001
& 1010101010101010
------------------
  1010101010101000
```

The same goes for the 0x5555.  5 = 0101.  Hopefully you get the idea.

The binary or operator on the other hand returns a 1 in every place where the binary numbers have a 1, as in:

```
  1010
| 0101
------
  1111
```

The bit shift operators ( >> and << ) move each binary digit one place over (depending on the direction of the arrows) and so on.  The hex is just a nicer format to visualize the bits without having to write out every single bit.

Answer (score 3):

It's [hexadecimal notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Using_0.E2.80.939_and_A.E2.80.93F). The "0x" indicates that it's a hexadecimal number, the rest of the digits are the value. The prepended 0x is a standard convention used in many systems and languages, such as C and its descendants, Unix Shell, Windows Powershell.

AAAA is equal to 43690 in base 10 (standard decimal). Similarly, 0x5555 = 21845. Hex is a common base to work with during bitwise operations (which is what's happening in your code), because the base is a power of two and it's much more compact to write out than binary.